# $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z} )/ \langle(3,3,3)\rangle$ is isomorphic to what?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, simple-groups

The solution told me it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, but why couldn't we argue that $(1,0,0), (0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ all generates infinite groups, so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Because $(1,1,1)$ has order $3$, and there is no such element in $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Because for a proposed homomorphism $(\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z)/\langle(3,3,3)\rangle\to X$ that you want to obtain from some $f\colon \Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to X$, you must always verify that $(3,3,3)\in\ker f$.

Comment: In $\Bbb Z$, you have that $1$, $2$ and $3$ generate infinite groups. This does not mean that $\Bbb Z\cong \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I thought initially.

In vector spaces, if $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis, then $\{v_1+v_2+v_3,v_2,v_3\}$ is also a basis (since every element in one set can be obtained from elements of other set and these sets have same cardinality).

Similarly, $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ can be considered as group with (basis) generating set $\{(1,1,1), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$ instead of $\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$; then the answer to your question is almost clear. I hope this clarifies your question a little and you can fill the details.